# Computing combinations of replaced values while keeping order of the list

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

I have a list of values: `[value1, value2, value3]`, and I am trying to generate all combinations of replacements with some default value (`DEFAULT`).

Basically, result like this.

```
[value1, value2, value3]
[DEFAULT, value2, value3]
[value1, DEFAULT, value3]
[value1, value2, DEFAULT]
[DEFAULT, DEFAULT, value3]
[value1, DEFAULT, DEFAULT]
[DEFAULT, value2, DEFAULT]
[DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT]
```

Is there some straightforward way to do this without recursion, or is some DFS the only option?

I have found multiple answers regarding computing combinations and variations of multiple lists, but I think this is a different problem since I need to keep the lists in the same order and replace combinations of some elements with a single value.

Comment: Do you always have 3 elements? Then you can just write a stupid function that directly returns these 8 lists. If you might have an arbitrary number of elements, please define the order you seek.

Comment: @Dmitry Unfortunately, no. I can have 1-N elements. The order of the rows can be random. I cannot change the order of the elements, though (aka. place `value1` on seconds position of the array).

Comment: Then I suggest to remove everything related to the order from the question. It's clear that you want to preserver the order of elements in the list, and "keep the lists in the same order" sounds like you want to have some order of rows.

Comment: While I don't see what's wrong with recursion, you can achieve this by iterating over the bit masks: `for mask in 0 ... 2^n - 1: ...`, where $n$ is the length of the list, and the $i$-th bit of the $mask$ is set iff you want to replace the $i$-th element with `DEFAULT`. You may also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

Comment: Thank you! The idea with using mask is brilliant! I will use that.